# Getting escaped quotes in HTML source code for JSON key and value

Tags: java, html, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have a problem regarding serialized JSON via Java on HTML source code.
I serialized the json as I need to have it in the HTML source code, but somehow the quotes for the JSON key like `"key":"value"` are showing as escaped when I view html source code.example :

`[{"title":"test-title"}]` becomes `[{&#34;title&#34;:&#34;test-title&#34;}]`

So the `"` is getting escaped to `&#34;` Now, as soon as the DOM is rendered and javascript kicks in this becomes fine. But i need the correct structure with `"` instead of `&#34;` in the source HTML code. Does anyone know how to deal with this? or if it's even possible to do this? I am happy to provide with more details if required.

Comment: Sorry, but what the difference `[{"title":"test-title"}] becomes [{"title":"test-title"}]` ?

Comment: @Igor Stackoverflow converts character entity references so you see the characters, not the entity reference (actually, just the web browser does this normally) — I edited the question to make those inline code so SO will leave them as entities.

Comment: @StephenP thnx!

Comment: @karanaug88 Can you provide some details? How are you serializing your JSON? It's not clear for me where the quotation marks look normal, and where they have already changed

Comment: @IgorGrange : i was serializing my json in java through GSON API.Then I was passing this data to my react component via data attributes.

data-serialized-json="my serialized json here"

the qutoes around keys and values were appearing normally on the rendered HTML (after Javascript kicks in)

And if I look at the generated HTML source code I could see that the JSON data being passed to react was appearing as escaped.